# Get single row instead of two data rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql ;

```
select 
Program,
CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 0 THEN COUNT(ClassMissed) ELSE 0 END as Completed,
CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 1 THEN COUNT(ClassMissed) ELSE 0 END as One_Days_Missed,
CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 2 THEN COUNT(ClassMissed) ELSE 0 END as Two_Days_Missed,
CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 3 THEN COUNT(ClassMissed) ELSE 0 ENd as Three_Days_Missed
from
#temp
group by Program,ClassMissed
```

Which gives me below out put:

```html
Program | Completed | One_Days_Missed | Two_Days_Missed |Three_Days_Missed
________________________________________________________________________________
Prog1   | 0       |      19   |      0     |       0 
Prog1 |       0       |      0   |      0     |       2
```

But I'm expecting below table

```html
Program | Completed | One_Days_Missed | Two_Days_Missed |Three_Days_Missed
________________________________________________________________________________
Prog1   | 0       |      19   |      0     |       2
```

I have to do the group by **Classmissed** in order to run the query.

Please give me better solution for this ?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide some sample data

Comment: @wewesthemenace you did it..!! Great work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SUM(CASE WHEN..END)`.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp(
    Program     VARCHAR(20),
    ClassMissed INT
)
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1),
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1),
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1),
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1),
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1),
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 3),
('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 1), ('Prog1', 3);

SELECT 
    Program,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS One_Days_Missed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Two_Days_Missed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ClassMissed = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Three_Days_Missed
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY Program

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

**RESULT**

```
Program              Completed   One_Days_Missed Two_Days_Missed Three_Days_Missed
-------------------- ----------- --------------- --------------- -----------------
Prog1                0           19              0               2
```

Comment: Thanks @wewesthemenace.. Appreciate it.. This worked for me.. !!